# alternate way to pass the state value of the container in which <FORM/> is rendered to the custom fields of the form(other than formcontext)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Is there any way to pass the state value of the container in which  is rendered to the custom fields of the form(Need a way other than formcontext).

```
class Example extends react.component{
   constructor(props){super(props);this.state={"some stuff"}
}
render(){
return(<Form
"somestuff"
formcontext={this.state}
/>)
}
}
```

Comment: For More information : Library used is the react-json form.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `React.Context`

Try the following code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";
const FormContext = React.createContext("FormContext");

function Form(props) {
  console.log(props);
  return <form />;
}

class SomethingElse extends React.Component {
  static contextType = FormContext;
  render() {
    return <Form values={this.context} />;
  }
}

const SomethingInTheMiddle = props => {
  return <SomethingElse />;
};

class Example extends React.Component {
  state = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <FormContext.Provider value={this.state}>
        <SomethingInTheMiddle />
      </FormContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Example />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Check more: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html